# How to arrange these tab/bubble elements in a div based on their content width using css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am trying to place some elements with text content generated from backend in a container div.
This is the HTML :

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="1"> ASDdjiajwio </div>
  <div class="2"> asdasda  </div>
  <div class="3"> asdgrsgse </div>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="5"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="n"> and so on.. </div>
</div>
```

Below image shows how i want them to be placed.

This is how I want the elements to be placed:

[image]

I could use grid for this, where the css goes like this:

```css
.mainContainer{
       width: 30em;
       height: 20em;
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

but then it will look like this -

This is how it looks

[image]

I want all the elements to be wrapped properly in the container div using css. Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you are looking for, simply do

```
.mainContainer div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Code Explanation

Inline-block

> displays an element as an inline-level block container. The element itself is formatted as an inline element, but you can apply height and width values

```css
.mainContainer div{
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid pink;
 border-radius: 25px;
 margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocks</title>
  <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling 
       rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="1"> ASDdjiajwio </div>
  <div class="2"> asdasda  </div>
  <div class="3"> asdgrsgse </div>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="5"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="6"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="7"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="5"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="3"> asdgrsgse </div>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="5"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="6"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="7"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="5"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="3"> asdgrsgse </div>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="5"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="6"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="7"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>
  <div class="4"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="n"> and so on.. </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is helpful to you

```
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="one"> ASDdjiajwio </div>
  <div class="one"> asdasda  </div>
  <div class="one"> asdgrsgse </div>
  <div class="one"> sdf sfsef </div>
  <div class="one"> asdahtd sfsefse </div>

  <div class="one"> and so on.. </div>
</div>
```

In CSS

```
.mainContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

}
.one
{
   border:2px solid #ef75db;
       border-radius:30px;
       text-align:center;
       margin:15px;
       padding:15px;
       color:#ef75db;
       font-size:18px;
}
```

Here is the working Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/86g20h39/8/

Comment: Thank you but I need those bubbles one after the other with  a common small gap between them.

Comment: I think you got an answer from Tien ... Good Luck